# I am trying to check the mysql bind address int the terminal but keep getting error can someone help?

Tags: bash, mysql

I am trying to check the mysql bind address in the terminal using the command `cat/etc/hosts | grep localhosts` that I got offline, but I keep getting a `bash: cat/etc/hosts: no such file or directory` error can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the command and its arguments with whitespace. In this case, `cat` is the command, and `/etc/hosts` is its argument. You also have a `grep` command with `localhosts` as argument, there you do have the required whitespace. So `cat/etc/hosts` should be `cat /etc/hosts`.

Now, if you want to query the hosts database, I recommend using the `getent` command instead of grepping `/etc/hosts` directly.

```
getent hosts localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with:

```
cat /etc/hosts | grep localhost
```

...? Is more efficient as long as bash does not recognize yet commands and arguments written together without spaces.

So add a space between `cat` and `/etc/hosts` and `grep` for `localhost`, not `localhosts`.